# Can't login anymore via sshd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, authentication, login

I have been working with SSH for a long time, but recently I have needed to add another user to my set up. I followed some instructions I found on the web and did the folllowing.

```
adduser sam
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
     AllowUsers michael, sam
sudo reboot
```

I set up the user sam completely, added the allow users to the sshd configuration and rebooted. Now michael is sudoer, but the funny thing is, I can login via ssh with Sams credentials but not michaels anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: By "michael is the root user", do you mean michael has user id 0, or michael has sudo permissions?

Comment: Ahh yes, (I believe), he is the account that was set up with the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `man sshd_config`:

```
AllowUsers
This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.
```

Then, your line have to be in this form:

```
AllowUsers michael sam
```

Comment: Under voting of answer you can see big check sign :-) But, be honest, I pretend, that list of users will be separated by coma too...